# Changes to columns displayed in the vSphere Client do not persist after restarting the client

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vsphere-client

I'm using the latest VMware vSphere Client, and I'm having an issue where changes I made to the columns view in the client aren't preserved.
VMware described this issue in kb 1030614 ([link‌](https://kb.vmware.com/kb/1030614)).

The suggested solution in the kb is to modify the relevant registry key. However, it's working only if the user implements the registry modification when the vSphere Client is running, and then change the view in the client between some other tab and the required tab in order to see the change.
For example, if the user wants to modify the "Virtual Machines" tab, he needs to modify the VMHeaderColumnsProp data as explained in the kb, and while the client is running, and then he needs to go back to the client and switch to some other tab and go back to the "Virtual Machines" tab to see the change.

Implementing the registry change while the client isn't running won't help since when it'll load it'll revert the changes that were made.
In addition, setting this key with no permissions so he won't be modified won't help since the client needs to modify it while it's running.

My temporary solution is running the client via a batch file and include a timeout of a few seconds, after which the registry modification will take place.

Here is an example for the relevant commands:

> start /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\Infrastructure\Virtual Infrastructure Client\Launcher" VpxClient.exe
>
> timeout 10 /nobreak >nul
>
> reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\VMware\VMware Infrastructure Client\Preferences\UI" /v VMHeaderColumnsProp /t REG_SZ /d "0-136,25-437,19-87,22-240,1-91,2-81,20-103,21-110,9-173,10-85,3-158,4-100,5-100,6-95,7-95,8-95,11-0,12-0,13-0,14-0,15-0,16-0,17-0,18-0,23-0,24-0,26-110,27-0,28-0,29-109,30-84,31-97,32-99,33-77,34-56,35-72" /f >nul

Does anyone know about another permanent solution?

`This issue is reproducible in the following VMware vSphere Client
versions:`

5.5.0 build 2417603

5.5.0 build 4032365